# How to relaunch a singleTask Activity without affect its behaviour

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have an Activity which is singleTask, and i want to relaunch (reshow) this Activity when user clicks in a button.

When i first call the activity it will play a music based in some data passed via Intent. But when the user press back to my MainActivity he will be able to press a button to bring he back to the Player activity. The problem is that when the user presses the button, the activity is relaunched, but it not seems to be via `onNewIntent` because it starts to play again from the beggining (sends the original playlist to service starting from beggining).

Is there to just reshow the activity without "doing nothing", just continuing what was doing previously?

**EDIT**:

Thats how im calling my singleTask Activity:

```
littlePlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!isPlaying) {
                        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player_.class);
                        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        it.putExtra("json", lastJson);
                        it.putExtra("position", position);
                        it.putExtra("playing_position", playingPosition);
                        startActivity(it);
                    }else{
                        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player_.class);
                        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(it);
                        //Player_.intent(MainActivity.this).start();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your activity as `singleTop` from `singleTask` to avoid relaunching the activity.

Then, call your activity like this,

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Im not using a Notification. I just have a button and when i click i create a (simple not Peding) intent that calls the activity. Can you provide more code about this? Im not getting pretty well.

Comment: Can you post your code so that I can understand your problem better?

Comment: Ok...its weird... i use the code edited and the activity is called without reload the player...the problem is that onNewIntent is never called and the views are not the same way when i pressed the back button, in fact they are not initialized anymore (as if the activity has reloaded). I dont know if its because im using android annotations and the behaviour is different, but is not working as i expected.

Comment: I made some changes in my code to make it work, but your help was essential. Thanks man, my app now is starting to get beautiful :P

Comment: Hey man...is there a way to launch the activity without get onCreate called?